# Vectorize Scala function with multiple return values

Tags: scala

What is the most elegant way to vectorize a scala function that returns multiple values?

For example, suppose I have the function:

```
def Foobar(foo: Int, bar: Int): (Int, Int) = (foo, bar)
```

If it returned a single value, I would do something like this:

```
val a = Array(1, 2, 3)
val b = Array(4, 5, 6)
val c = (a,b).zipped.map(foobar)
```

But since it returns a tuple, I end up with an `Array[(Int,Int)]`, whereas I would prefer an `(Array[Int], Array[Int])`.  What is the proper way to do something like this?  Are there any clever patterns for generalizing this to something like this:

```
val c = vectorized(foobar,a,b)
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can unzip it (obviously, it operation which is oposite to zip):

```
val c = foobar(a,b).unzip
//res2: (s.c.m.IndexedSeq[Int], s.c.m.IndexedSeq[Int]) = (ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3),ArrayBuffer(4, 5, 6))
```

But you'll end up with IndexedSeqs, not Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can certainly write a `vectorized` function if you want, though you need a different one for every input and output arity.  Here's the 2.10 version (2.9 would use `Manifest` instead of `ClassTag`) for two in and two out:

```
import reflect.ClassTag
def vectorized[A, B, C: ClassTag, D: ClassTag](
  f: (A,B) => (C,D), a: Array[A], b: Array[B]
): (Array[C], Array[D]) = {
  val c = Array.newBuilder[C]
  val d = Array.newBuilder[D]
  for (i <- 0 until math.min(a.length, b.length)) {
    val x = f(a(i), b(i))
    c += x._1
    d += x._2
  }
  (c.result, d.result)
}
```

Comment: @ziggystar - Why would you?  Shapeless is designed for maximum power of the type system, not performance!  You could probably use debox.

Comment: You're probably right that you won't get a shapeless solution as far as to avoid boxing. Will your solution box the arguments to `f`?

Comment: @ziggystar - Sorry, I had my questions confused!  Maybe you could use _shapeless_ here, and it would be fine.  You would box the arguments in this case; you'd need to specialize to avoid that.  (Specializing fully on four arguments gives you on the order of 10,000 classes, so that is not wise.)